# Tails "clone" LiveUSB wont boot

Tags: linux, uefi, liveusb, tails

I'll try to be as clear as possible.

I did install Tails to a USB, then I cloned it over another USB and thats where the problems started.

The "clone tails usb" won't start in my laptop. I did try to boot it in another computer and it does starts fine.

The computer says something as "no OS found", but as i stated, there is and actually it does work in other computers.

My laptop is a Samsung series 9 and I use LUNA and Win8. So far I never had any trouble to start a USB live, however with the "clone tails" I am puzzled. I have not idea what else to try.

At the BIOS there is the option to "disable" UEFI, but nothing as Legacy, CMS or such things.

Weird thing is that the first USB works fine, but the "clone tails" won't boot at all, even when using the same computer.

As I said already, I don't have any trouble at all to boot any LiveUSB, but this "cloned" live USB is driving me mad.

Any help would be very welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "cloned"? How did you clone it?  How did you build the original USB image you cloned?  What happens if you build it the original way on the key which isn't working?

Comment: in order to have a persistence tails USB,  you need to copy tails to a USB , boot it  and then , clone it ( using tails own app/software ) to a second USB. This second or "clone" USB will be be a persistence volume, in which you will be bale to make updates among other things. The original USB was build using unetbootin and it does work flawlessly. I did try different  USB , same result.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you use the "Tails Installer" from a live Tails to create the second USB ? And is it this newly created USB that is not booting ? Does the first USB still boot to a live Tails OS ? Have you configured your BIOS boot order to try USB first, then disk, then network ?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking with GParted if your cloned USB has the correct flags set at the partition that holds your cloned Tails files, I suspect this might be the cause. 
You should be able to check all the right flags with an genuine Tails LiveUSB, but at least include legacy-boot flag.

(sorry if I'm necro-thread posting here)

Comment: Answering and old question is encouraged if you have an answer. This is more of a suggestion of something to try, which may be more appropriate as a comment (you will be able to comment once you have a little reputation).